# Trying to install 18.04 classic on Pi 3 B+, close but not quite there

Tags: networking, system-installation, 18.04, raspberrypi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 server onto a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using these instructions:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

I chose to download ubuntu-18.04.1-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz for Pi 2 and convert for 3 B+ as described in the instructions.

The boot up looked SO promising, but when the login screen came up, it immediately printed about 25 lines related to SSH keys and then hung.  I attached a photo but it was basically:

```
ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS ubuntu tty1

ubuntu login: [ 32.797] cloud-init[1186]: Cloud-init v. 18.2 running 'modules:config' at Sun, 28 Jan 2018...
ci-info: no authorized ssh keys fingerprints found for user ubuntu.
ec2:  -----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2:  1024 SHA256:......
ec2:  256 SHA256:.....
...
...
ec2:  -----END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2:
BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
...and a few more lines relating to SSH
```

But then it hangs.

Has anyone seen this or know how to get past this point?

[picture of boot screen when it hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPveM.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection?  The wiki link you provided lists that as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, actually I need to revise (or remove if possible) my question.  I didn't realize at the time, it wasn't hanging, it was waiting for me to enter login credentials.  I actually was able to login using ubuntu/ubuntu.  But upon logging in, I learned I was not connected to my network.  So my next task is trying to figure out why the network connection isn't working.

Comment: Networking is resolved.  As it turned out, when I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Pi 3 B+ using those instructions, for whatever reason it did not create a /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file.  I copied in the following from another Ubuntu 18.04 server:
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
On reboot, it pulled an ip address and I'm now up and running.  I'll leave this in case someone else can benefit.